# Compile Jigsaw multi module

Tags: java, multi-module, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I'm tried to get Jigsaw working using a multi module project, but without any luck.

```
src
 +----com.example.foo
 |      |
 |      |--- Foo.java
 |
 +----com.example.bar
 |      |
 |      |--- Bar.java
 |
 +----readymodules
        |
        + Foo
        |   |
        |   |--- nodule-info.java
        |
        + Bar
             |
             |--- module-info.java
```

Content of src/readymodules/Foo/nodule-info.java

```
 module readymodules.Foo {
     exports com.example.foo;
 }
```

Xontent of src/readymodules/Bar/nodule-info.java

```
 module readymodules.Bar {
     exports com.example.Bar;
     requires readymodules.Foo;
 }
```

Now I want to compile using (I'm in parent of src)

```
$ javac -d mods --module-source-path src $(find src -name "*.java")
 src/com/example/foo/Foo.java :1: error: not in a module on the module source path
 package com.example.foo;
 src/com/example/bar/Bar.java :1: error: not in a module on the module source path
 package com.example.bar;
 src/readymodules/Bar/module-info.java:1: error: module not found on     module source path
  module readymodules.Bar
 package com.example.foo;
 src/readymodules/Foo/module-info.java:1: error: module not found on      module source path
 module readymodules.Foo
```

What do I wrong?

Comment: Hopefully, the [jigsaw quick start](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start) can help you understand the hierarchy/structure to be followed.

Comment: I see a couple of typos saying "nodule-info" instead of "module-info". Is that just here in the question or do you have that typo as well in your source code?

Comment: Why are you putting the `module-info.java` in a separate directory instead of at the root of each actual module (com/example/foo and com/example/bar)?